# Values of k for a system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Give all values of $k$ such that the system

$$\begin{cases}x+y+2z=4\\kx+(k^2+k-1)y+2kz=5k+1\\-kx-ky-kz=-3k\end{cases}$$

in the variables $x,\, y$ and $z$ has

a) no solutions

b) exactly one solution

c) infinitely many solutions

Augmented Matrix= $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        k & k^2+k-1 & 2k & 5k+1 \\
        -k & -k & -k & -3k \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

RREF= row 1 times $-k$ plus row 2, row 1 times $k$ plus row 3: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & k^2-1 & 0 & k+1 \\
        0 & 0 & k & k \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Special cases: $k^2-1=0=(k-1) (k+1),\, k=1,\, k=-1$

$k=1$: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ no solutions

$k=-1$: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

RREF: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ infinitely many solutions

This next part is the part im not understanding. $k\neq 1$, $k\neq -1$, and $k\neq 0$ are exactly one solution but I don't see how it was figured out.

$k\neq 1,\,k\neq-1$: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & * \\
        0 & 0 & k & k \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Special case:

$k=0$: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & * \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ infinitely many solutions

$k\neq 1,\,k\neq -1,\,k\neq 0$: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & * \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & * \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & * \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ exactly one solution

Answer:

No solutions: $k=1$

Exactly one solution: $k\neq 1,\, k\neq -1,\, k\neq0$

Infinitely many solutions: $k=-1,\, k=0$

Answer (score 0):

The case $k \ne 1$, $k\ne 1$, $k\ne 0$ can be concluded from your second version of the system

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & k^2 - 1 & 0 & k+ 1 \\ 0 & 0 &k & k\end{array}\right)
$$

From this

1. $\color{blue}{kz = k}$

   Since $k \ne 0$ then

   > $$z = 1$$
2. $\color{blue}{(k^2 - 1)y = k + 1}$

   In this case since $k\ne \pm 1$ then $k^2 - 1 \ne 0$ and

   > $$
   >    y = \frac{k + 1}{k^2 - 1}
   >    $$
3. $\color{blue}{x + y + 2z = 4}$

   > $$
   >    x = 4 - y - 2z = 4 - \frac{k + 1}{k^2 - 1} - 2 = \frac{2k^2 + k - 1}{k^2 - 1}
   >    $$

That is the *unique* solution